# Bootstrap 3.3.2 modal issue with angular scope variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with bootstrap (v 3.2.0), angular (v 1.3.13) and jquery (v 2.1.3) and this issue is appearing when I'm trying to upgrade the bootstrap version to 3.3.2. We've a bootstrap modal which is toggled with angular route. The modal has $scope bound variables.

In v 3.2.0, the $scope bound variables are appearing fine in the modal, but in v 3.3.2 angular is throwing an error 
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

I've created two examples also:

- With bootstrap v 3.2.0 ($scope vars working) : http://plnkr.co/edit/cGf3C2gHR0GOK5JBido1?p=preview

  `Inside the controller: $scope.helloString = "Hello from Scope";`
- With bootstrap v 3.3.2 ($scope vars not working) : http://plnkr.co/edit/kj66Gal5s5Yczyom1PHC?p=preview

  `In the modal html: 
   <div class="modal-body"> 
     <p> {{helloString}} </p>
   </div>`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's much better to use one of the Angular ports of Bootstrap's JS (e.g. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ) than to use Bootstrap's original jQuery-based JS.

Comment: Agreed with cvrebert, use Angular UI's directive implementations of Bootstrap features. Save yourself unnecessary time frustration spent.

Comment: I understand, but still would like to know where the issue is. It's a live app we're dealing with and not always easy to include another library. Also,  shouldn't it be better for upgrades to just deal with pure bootstrap/jquery instead of another library which is dependent on bootstrap?